# Is there any way to create a radio-button Sub-menu?

Tags: android, radio-button, submenu

I have a `Sub-Menu` that I made. But, I can only figure out how to make it so that user can check multiple things. But, sadly, I can't find any `attributes` that make it `to check only one thing at a time`, or a radio button. Could anyone tell me this attribute?

Comment: Help, please? It would be nice...

Comment: How did you make that checkboxes? Could you show your code?

Comment: <item android:id="@+id/x3" android:title="3x3x3" android:checkable="false" android:checked="true" android:enabled="true" android:visible="true"/>
                    <item android:id="@+id/x4" android:title="4x4x4" android:checkable="true" android:checked="false" android:enabled="true" android:visible="true"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/x5" android:title="5x5x5" android:checkable="true" android:checked="false" android:enabled="true" android:visible="true"/>

Comment: You should always edit your question with your code. It's difficult for others to understand this unformatted code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it with the following.

```
<!--Normal View-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--Radio group that makes only one selected item-->
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <!--Different buttons-->
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn1" />

        <!-- sub buttons -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radios_extra">
            <!-- fill this radio group with extra items and when check btn1 change the visivility for VISIBLE -->
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:id="@+id/extra_group"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bt2" />

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```